# MS Dynamics CRM Form Field OnChange check for Existing Value in Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Unless someone can explain what I'm missing, CRM 2013 does not have any way to check for a duplicate WHILE entering a new Lead record.  I want to check for a duplicate BEFORE the new record is saved.  I can't seem to figure this one out.

Basically, when a user enters the Company Name on a new Lead record, I'd like JavaScript or something check for the existence of that value in all the other Lead records and return True or False.  That way I can alert the user that the Company already exists BEFORE they save the new record.

Make sense?  Am I just TOTALLY missing something here?

Thanks,

Scotty

Comment: Use FetchXML via JavaScript. http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2011/07/using-the-fetchxml-crm-2011-service-within-a-javascript-web-resource/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft removed this functionality. But you can restore it using one of following articles:

http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-turn-on-duplicate-detection-for.html
http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2013/10/are-you-missing-duplicate-detection-in.html

Comment: Any reason for removing duplicate detection by Microsoft?

Comment: I'll check this out too!

Comment: I think this is going to work, except when the dialog pops up to alert the user to the duplicate, there is no message.  Just a blank dialog.

Comment: Well, had to change my answer.  I think it's close, but I'm having issues with it working.  I think it will work eventually, but I need some help with it.

Basically, it's not allowing ANY records to be created.  The dialog box that pops up is empty, and there is no "Save Anyway" option.  Got any ideas?

Comment: Which of articles have you used?

Comment: I used the first one you posted... "...how-to-turn-on-duplicate..."

Comment: Ok, I just discovered something.  I changed my parameters to match exactly what was in the instructions and it worked.  Unfortunately, it's checking fields that I don't want/need to.  

It's checking: ["subject","fullname", "firstname", "lastname","emailaddress1","address1_city"],

I want: ["companyname","fullname", "firstname", "lastname","emailaddress1"],

Comment: Could you please post full configuration you've used?

Comment: Sure: Ok, just for clarification, I've not altered the .js file at all.  The only thing I've changes is in the Form Properties > OnSave > Comma Separated List of Parameters...

This one works, which is straight from the documentation:
false,
"lead", 
"leadid", 
["subject","fullname", "firstname", "lastname","emailaddress1","address1_city"],
"sample_/duplicateDetection/ShowDuplicateLeads.html",
"dialogHeight: 250px; dialogWidth: 650px; resizable: yes; status: no;"
>>>continued...

Comment: ...

This one seems to work, but it still shows the "subject" as one of the columns in the resulting dialog:
false,
"lead", 
"leadid", 
["companyname","fullname", "firstname", "lastname","emailaddress1","address1_city"],
"sample_/duplicateDetection/ShowDuplicateLeads.html",
"dialogHeight: 250px; dialogWidth: 650px; resizable: yes; status: no;"
>>>continued...

Comment: ...
This one, again, seems to find duplicates, but doesn't show my columns in the resulting dialog.  Only SUBJECT, FULLNAME, CITY, EMAIL:
false,
"lead", 
"leadid", 
["companyname","fullname", "firstname", "lastname","emailaddress1"],
"sample_/duplicateDetection/ShowDuplicateLeads.html",
"dialogHeight: 250px; dialogWidth: 650px; resizable: yes; status: no;"

Comment: Now, when I say they "work", I mean it finds duplicates.  I just want to be sure it's basing is comparison on the fields I've defined, specifically: COMPANYNAME, FULLNAME, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, EMAILADDRESS1.

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured this out.  SO Sorry for the copious amounts of posts. I think this is the answer to my problem cause it's working.  I simply have to figure out how to change the resulting dialog.  I'll post that question in your blog.  I will mark this as answered.  Thanks again for all your patience and excellent suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to check duplicate records and set alert/field value depending upon result set :

```js
CheckDuplicate: function (someIdentifier) {
        var value = null;
        var filter = "?$select=*&$filter=(new_Identifier eq '" + someIdentifier + "') and (new_someGuidField/Id eq guid'" + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_someGuidField").getValue()[0].id + "')";
        retrieveMultipleSync("new_EntityNameSet", filter, function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                value = data;
                }
            }, null);
        return value;
    }
```